# Induction axiom and its logical properties

Tags: logic, natural-numbers

Is the induction axiom (postulated in the Peano Axioms or in Dedekinds version using only FOL) a logical truth or a contigent truth (so that it could turn out false)?

IMO the induction axiom would be a contigent truth even in the following case, namely when we would interpret ℕ = {0, 1, 2, …, 1.000.000.000} where we would just additionally postulate in the axioms that 1.000.000.000 is the „last natural number“, i.e. having no successor. Correct?

Because logical truth means true in any interpretation of the symbols and obviously you could interpret some symbols in the induction axiom so that it becomes false.

But even if we focus just on the standard interpretation of the induction axiom in the Peano Axioms it could be false, right? Because we cannot prove it, so how could we be sure that it is true after all? Postulating truth as an axiom has nothing to do with being true, right?

Comment: $(1)$ In real math, there is no largest positive integer $(2)$ Informally speaking , the induction works for every positive integer because every positive integer is finite, so is eventually reached by repeated adding $1$ no matter how many additions we might need. $(3)$ The induction axiom is equivalent to the principle that every nonempty set of positive integers has a smallest element.

Comment: If $N$ were the largest natural in some suitable alternative theory where that makes sense, induction would work as thus: if $\varphi(0)$ (change this to $\varphi(1)$ is you start naturals at $1$) and $k=N\lor(\varphi(k)\to\varphi(k^+))$ for naturals $k$, $\varphi(n)$ for naturals $n$.

Comment: Already [asked yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4398823/induction-axiom-logical-truth): what about the answer provided there?

Comment: The question was closed and demanded to be edited, so I did but it didn‘t change, so therefore my new try. I think safe to say that the induction axiom is not a logical truth. But what is interesting still: even if we interpret it with the standard interpretation of natural numbers it can be false just because it is an unproven axiom, right?

Answer (score 1):

(1) "A logical truth or a contingent truth" aren't exhaustive options. Something can be necessarily true, non-contingent, without being a truth of logic. Arguably the induction principle holds necessarily of the natural numbers, in virtue of the way the natural numbers form an $\omega$-sequence. That doesn't make it a truth of logic (in the normally understood sense).

(2) You might find the following helpful: §9.1(a) and §13.1 of *An Introduction to Gödel's Theorems*, downloadable from https://www.logicmatters.net/igt .

Comment: So you would agree that the induction axiom of PA can turn out false, even in the standard interpretation, while something like A v ~A (logical truth) can never?

Comment: No. On the standard interpretation it is necessarily true.

Comment: How do you know that, given that it is an unprovable non-tautological axiom?

Comment: But you have fixed on an interpretation (and you were talking about the formal sentence on its standard interpretation). So the formal sentence now expresses a determinate proposition. It is that which is necessarily true.

Comment: Even in a fixed interpretation only a tautology is necessarily true, but the induction axiom is no tautology but has only the form of an implication A -> B and such is just contigent. So in my option we assume the induction axiom to be true without proof but this is just an assumption that can be false like any assumption of contigent truths.